# Remap database using key

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

I have a dataset to update using a key-dataset.
I would like to change entries in a dataset (group_1:group_3) to their corresponding value.

Mind that in reality my key dataset has +25k entries and seeking for an efficient solution is what takes me here! All help appreciated.

Toy example

```
df <- data.frame(state=rep("state_a"),
             candidate=c("a","b","c"),
             group_1= c("g_1","g_2","g_3"),
             group_2= c("g_4","g_5",NA),
             group_3= c("g_5",NA,NA))

key <- data.frame(group=c("g_1","g_2","g_3","g_4","g_5"),
              leader=c("l_1","l_2","l_3","l_4","l_4"))
```

Result:

```
df <- data.frame(state=rep("state_a"),
             candidate=c("a","b","c"),
             group_1= c("g_1","g_2","g_3"),
             group_2= c("g_4","g_5",NA),
             group_3= c("g_5",NA,NA))
```

ADDITIONAL REQUEST:
I would like to use `df_2` (same dimension as `df`) to decide which entries in  to keep `df_final`, then transform.

```
df_2 <- data.frame(state=rep("state_a"),
                   candidate=c("a","b","c"),
                   value_1= c("1","2","0"),
                   value_2= c("3","2",NA),
                   value_3= c("5",NA,NA))

df_final_temp <- data.frame(state=rep("state_a"),
             candidate=c("a","b","c"),
             group_1= c("g_1","g_2",NA),
             group_2= c("g_4","g_5",NA),
             group_3= c("g_5",NA,NA))

df_final <- data.frame(state=rep("state_a"),
             candidate=c("a","b","c"),
             group_1= c("l_1","l_2",NA),
             group_2= c("l_4","l_5",NA),
             group_3= c("l_5",NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use key/value pair as a named vector to match the columns

```
df[-(1:2)] <- setNames(as.character(key$leader), key$group)[as.matrix(df[-(1:2)])]    


df
#    state candidate group_1 group_2 group_3
#1 state_a         a     l_1     l_4     l_4
#2 state_a         b     l_2     l_4    <NA>
#3 state_a         c     l_3    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: why `as.matrix(df[-(1:2)])`?

Comment: @M-M `matrix` act like a `vector` (with some dim attributes).  So, it can be directly applied instead of looping through each column.  (Both have pros/cons)

Comment: I was thinking about using `unlist` instead of `as.matrix` :/

Comment: @M-M You can use that too, make sure that it is a character column instead of factor.  `matrix` converts to character

Comment: Can I use this method also to make slightly more complicated calculations?
Like, if the key is now:

key_2 <- data.frame(group=c("g_1","g_2","g_3","g_4","g_5"),
              values=c(1,2,3,4,0)

How would i use key_2 to  change observations that display value g_5 to NAs base of the fact that their value is 0?

Comment: @MCS Do you need `df[-(1:2)][df[-(1:2)] == "g_5"] <- NA`

Comment: @akrun I would like to drop from `df` any group that value==0 in `key_2`, but I do not know before hand which one are in which setting, the position in the matrix/dataset is revealing.
(the idea is that g_5 can support in different ways different candidates, and I want to keep g_5 in `df` only when it contributes to a candidate for a value different from 0)

Comment: @MCS Based on the expected, I would first convert the elements that are 0 in 'df_2" to NA.  `df_2[3:5][df_2[3:5] == 0] <- NA`

Comment: @MCS Also, make ssure that you create data.frame columns as `character` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as it can mess up the `factor` to integer conversion

Comment: The code transforms `df_2` alright, but I need it to transform `df` instead. For any position displaying a 0 in `df_2` I would like to see the corresponding group in `df` to be changed into a NA.

Comment: Okay, in that case `df[3:5][df_2[3:5] == 0]] <- NA` after doing the changes in `df` with key/val dataset

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be using `match`:

```r
df[-(1:2)] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) key[match(x, key$group),2]))
```